# how to get arguments on an event emitter in jasmine test

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing, spyon

I have a unit test as below

```
it('billing information is correct', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(component.myEventEmitter, 'emit').and.callThrough();
    component.form.controls['size'].setValue(12);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    **let args= component.myEventEmitter.emit.mostRecentCall **
    expect(args.billingSize).toEqual('30')
});
```

When size changes, myEventEmitter is being emitted with a large json object which includes billingSize. And I want the test to check if this value is as expected. But looks like I can't do 'mostRecentCall/ calls' on the event emitter. What can I try next?

Note: I don't want to do `expect(component.myEventEmitter.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(*dataExpected*)` because the dataExpected is a large JSON object. I just care about one field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
it('billing information is correct', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  spyOn(component.myEventEmitter, 'emit').and.callThrough();
  component.form.controls['size'].setValue(12);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let arg: any = (component.myEventEmitter.emit as any).calls.mostRecent().args[0];
  expect(arg.billingSize).toEqual('30');
});
```

note:

```
 component.myEventEmitter.emit.calls.mostRecent()
```

- wouldn't compile (error: calls does not exist on type ..') so type it to 'any' and should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```js
 expect(component.myEventEmitter.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('eventName', 
  jasmine.objectContaining(*dataExpected*)
);
```

Comment: But looks like objectContaining  expects the entire object. ( whole json object in my case). Can you provide an example?

Comment: @SoJosf You can take a look here https://github.com/robtweed/ewd-document-store/blob/master/spec/unit/proto/delete.spec.js#L52 I wrote these tests

Comment: I have tried it. 
_expect(component.taskRowData.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
            billingSize: 30
        }));_
  
But  think that is not quite useful in my case. The args in the eventEmitter looks like '{ taskRow: {'jsonobject'}, formValid: true}' 
The field I want to look for is inside 'jsonobject'.
I got this error: _Expected spy emit to have been called with [ <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ billingSize: 30 }))> ] but actual calls were [ Object({ taskRow: Object({ id: 1, name: 'Test task', billable: false, billingSize: 30, billingPrice: 26.46_ ...

Comment: expect(component.taskRowData.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    taskRow:  jasmine.objectContaining({
      billingSize: 30
    })
  })
);

Comment: Thanks Alexey for looking at this. But I am  getting the same error with objectContaining.